# Override Jquery Ajax with Formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, overriding

I'm trying to override jeury ajax with form data (having file as well), but it always return following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

But it is working fine when I pass array data instead of formdata.
I have tried both ajax and post but none of the code is working. Please do help guys.

Here is the post override:

```
// Store a reference to the original remove method.
var originalPostMethod = jQuery.post;
// Define overriding method.
jQuery.post = function () {
    // Execute the original method.

    if (window.user && window.user.user && window.user.user.csrf) {
        console.log('form data', arguments[1]);
        if (arguments[1] instanceof FormData) {
            arguments[1].set('csrf', window.user.user.csrf);
        }
        else {
            arguments[1].csrf = window.user.user.csrf;
        }
    }
    
    var callback = arguments[2];
    arguments[2] = function (data) {
        console.log('post data', data);
        if (data.new_csrf) {
            window.user.user.csrf = data.new_csrf;
        }
        callback(data);
    }
    
    console.log('this post', this);
    console.log('arguments post', arguments);
    var callMethod = originalPostMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    callMethod.error = callMethod.fail
    return callMethod
}
```

Here is the ajax override:

```
var originalAjaxMethod = jQuery.ajax;
jQuery.ajax = function () {
    if (arguments[0] && arguments[0].success) {
        var callback = arguments[0].success;
        arguments[0].success = function (data) {
            console.log('ajax data', data);
            if (data.new_csrf) {
                window.user.user.csrf = data.new_csrf;
            }
            callback(data);
        }

        if ($.inArray(arguments[0].type, ['post', 'POST']) !== -1 && window.user && window.user.user && window.user.user.csrf) {
            console.log('form data', arguments[0]);
            var reqData = arguments[0].data ? arguments[0].data : {};
            if (reqData instanceof FormData) {
                reqData.set('csrf', window.user.user.csrf);
            }
            else {
                reqData.csrf = window.user.user.csrf;
            }
            arguments[0].data = reqData;
        }
    }

    console.log('this ajax', this);
    console.log('arguments ajax', arguments);
    var callMethod = originalAjaxMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    callMethod.error = callMethod.fail;
    return callMethod;
}
```

This is not working:

```
$.post('url', formData, function (data) {

});
```

This is working:

```
$.post('url', {data: data}, function (data) {

});
```

Anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: Post https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/  is a shorthand method https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/ for `jQuery.ajax(` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You might also post the signature of your server side method to support your URL and the parameters being sent

Comment: Perhaps explain why you want to override it and deal with that complexity level instead of just using it?

Comment: Actually there is an api call in laravel, when I try to edit profile with image, csrf token expire. That's why I did overriding here. So at first call I get new csrf token and I'm adding new csrf token in request and making callback.